# How to Orderby User Role?

Tags: user-roles

Im looking to order posts by the users role...
I currently have 2 user roles (intending to create more), and they are "Premium User" and "User", and some poss created by "Admin"

All of these posts are on one page, and i would like all the posts that are written by the "Premium User" at the top, then the rest underneath.

I have currently accomplished this with 2 separate loops, however, as the site grows there will be need for pagination to be added, and with 2 separate loops, this isnt going to work.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Here is a similar Question and Answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20804/how-to-order-posts-by-custom-wp-role

Comment: Note that a user can have _multiple roles_, for example `administrator` and `zenmaster`. How should ordering work then?

Comment: I wasnt aware that I could assign the user to more than 1 role... For this website instance, they will only have 1 user role per user.

Failing that, if need be: Any user with the role "Premium User" would appear first.

Answer (score 2):

This one's a little difficult, as there's no default user role meta key or post data. The only thing we got is the user ID.

```
// Get the posts
$posts_by_author_ID = get_posts( array(
     'post_type'   => 'post'
    ,'post_status' => 'publish'
    ,'orderby'     => 'post_author'
    ,'order'       => 'DESC'
) );
foreach ( $posts_by_author_ID as $post )
{
    static $user;

    $new_user = get_user_by( 'id', $post->post_author );

    // Let's save some queries
    if ( 
        isset ( $user ) 
        AND $user->ID === $new_user->ID
    )
        continue;

    $user = $new_user;

    foreach ( $user->roles as $role )
    {
        $posts_by_author_role[ $role ] = array( 
             'user' => $user
            ,'post' => $post
        );
    }
}
// Sort by key a.k.a. role
ksort( $posts_by_author_ID );

echo '<pre>'; // Only for debugging/developing - should get deleted when done
foreach ( $posts_by_author_ID as $role => $data )
{
    list( $user, $post ) = $data;
    // Now we can output our data
    // The user data is saved inside $user
    // The actual post data is saved inside $data

    // The following is only for debugging/developing - should get deleted when done
    var_export( $user, false );
    var_export( $post, false );
}
echo '</pre>'; // Only for debugging/developing - should get deleted when done
```

Comment: Couldnt get this to work, or even display posts?
I think i edited parts wrong maybe...

Custom Post Type is called: Model
1st Role: Premium Models
2nd/3rd Role: Administrator / Model (no preference for ordering these

Potentially another one will be adde din future called "Super Premium Model"


Thanks,

Comment: @Mike You need the _internal_ name as @toscho pointed out in the comments to your question above ↑. This means it's not `Premium Models`, but something without spaces and lowercased like (for e.g.) `premium-models`. You should check this and use this user role. Also: Dump the `$posts_by_author_ID` to see if this part works, then we're proceeding further.

Comment: Hopefully this helps (it could be something else ive done wrong: http://pastebin.com/HNx6WkeD

Thanks

Comment: @Mike I asked you to _dump_ the result. Not showing my code inside your template (helps me nothing, as I don't have your setup + DB). Here's [a pastebin with debugging code](http://pastebin.com/d4XSjR9U). For the rest, you'll have to dig into it, learn some basic PHP to know what you're doing and then edit the/my answer above with what worked (without the actual surrounding template stuff).

Comment: Sorry, really struggling with this...

Its only outputting the Page, not the Posts in the Model custom post category, result here: www.lauralee-world.co.uk/ (NSFW)

Comment: @Mike Honestly: What shall I do with the link? Searching through source code and trying to _guess_ what happens? I even gave you pastebin, that will dump tons of data. Why don't you share the results?